# Язык Golang, мнение людей о будущем

Tags: golang

Какое будущее вы видите за языком программирования Golang? Это будущее, которое должно заменить большую часть сегмента и со временем войти в Android? Какие мысли? Стоит посвящать ему много времени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Войти в Android -- это зависит исключительно от левой пятки Google. Не так давно Google заявил о намерении сделать поддержку NDK для Go. Таким образом Java никуда не уйдёт, просто, возможно, часть игр будет писаться на Go.

Вообще на Go сейчас активно пишут новые проекты. Из известных -- docker.

> Какое будущее Вы видите за языком программирования Golang?

Хорошо, вдумчиво спроектированный язык, одновременно строгий и очень гибкий. По своим возможностям конкурентности встаёт в один ряд с Erlang. Определённо стоит обратить внимание.

IMHO: Один из немногих языков, который у меня повернётся язык назвать правильным. Остальные: Си, Scheme, Erlang.

> Стоит посвещать ему много времени?

Некоррестный вопрос, на него нельзя корректно ответить. Ты спрашиваешь "а нужен ли", тем самым призывая нас на религиозную войну. Решай, как тебе нравится.